# The JavaScript array's data gets copied to another array without the push() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've been programming using JS for about a half year now and suddenly, I've encountered a really strange behavior.

I'm creating a game and don't get confused with HTML or CSS part - **don't edit it**. JS needs it but there are no errors there.

So, I have two arrays: `queueToRemoveArr = []`, `queueToAddArr = []`.

Then, there is an `if` statement on line 53. If it is true, these two lines are executed:

```
console.log("remove live cells", rowArg, cellArg);
queueToRemoveArr.push($table.rows[rowArg].cells[cellArg]);
```

I'm using `console.log()` just to check which element it pushes to the array.

On line 58 there is another `if` with this content executed if it's true. **I've commented it out** so the problem is easier to solve.

```
//queueToAddArr.push($table.rows[rowArg].cells[cellArg]);
```

---

Let's run it and see what we get:
[image]
It's the first generation (in other words - first time I run the function `happyEventToCreateLiveCells`.

Everything looks ok like shown in the picture. 1 + 1 = 2 and that's how many elements there are in the `queueToRemoveArr` array. `queueToAddArr` array is empty because I don't do anything with it. No `push()`, nothing.

Let's run it again (second time):
[image]

And what happened here? Explain, please. The array `queueToRemoveArr` has one element in it, that's ok because 1 = 1 (see the photo?). But how in the earth did `queueToAddArr` get one item? And it's exactly the same item as specified in the `queueToRemoveArr` array.

I could've shown you what happens if we uncommented the `//queueToAddArr.push($table.rows[rowArg].cells[cellArg]);` line but I'll show you a picture. Exactly the same array. However, only the second time it runs.
[image]

The first time I run everything I try, it works. What's wrong running it the second time?

---

Can't add the stack snippet here because of the limitation of max 30000 characters but the problem I've described should be clear to you.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/NYzJLQ?editors=0010.

**WATCH ONLY THE JS PART.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line caused your issue:

```
 queueToRemoveArr = queueToAddArr = [];
```

It should be:

```
queueToRemoveArr =[];
queueToAddArr = [];
```

Comment: It fixed the issue but can I ask why? I'm assigning`[]` to the `queueToAddArr` and `queueToAddArr`  to the `queueToRemoveArr`. They are both `[]`, aren't?

Comment: I've learned so, e.g. `someVariable1 = someVariable2 = 0`, then both variables are equal to 0.

Comment: Your approach assign SAME empty array reference to both variables. So to fix it you should assign different empty arrays

Comment: Numbers and strings in JS are assigned by values, arrays and objects - by reference